# How to create a small bibtex file from a bigger one?

Tags: auctex, bibtex

**Q:** how do I create a stripped-down bibtex file based on the
citations used in a given paper?

I have a single, master bibtex file that contains thousands of
entries.  For most papers, I only ever use a few dozen of those
entries.

When I submit the final version of a paper to a journal for
publication, I need to give them a bibtex file as well.  Rather
than give them my behemoth bibtex file, I would prefer to give
them a stripped down version that only includes the entries I used
in the paper.

How would I automate the process of creating the stripped-down
bibtex file from the master file?

(I'm using AUCTeX, and would prefer not to get `org-mode` involved
in the process if possible.)

Comment: A generic solution using `biblatex`:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212134/30158

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`reftex` has the command `reftex-create-bibtex-file` that you can call via the menu `Ref -> Global Actions -> Create BibTeX File`.

I cite the help of `reftex-create-bibtex-file` here:

> Create a new BibTeX database BIBFILE with all entries referenced in document.
>   The command prompts for a filename and writes the collected
>   entries to that file.  Only entries referenced in the current
>   document with any \cite-like macros are used.  The sequence in
>   the new file is the same as it was in the old database.
>
> Entries referenced from other entries must appear after all
>   referencing entries.
>
> You can define strings to be used as header or footer for the
>   created files in the variables ‘reftex-create-bibtex-header’ or
>   ‘reftex-create-bibtex-footer’ respectively.